# Delay PHP echo, without halting the page?

Tags: php, echo, delay

I want to draw text after 1 second delays, without halting the page load for the duration of all of the delays in total.

Does anyone know how?

I have the below, but rather than drawing the TIME and "Hello", then waiting a second and drawing "Goodbye", followed by another second and finally "The End".... It waits 2 seconds and then draws everything.

```
<?php

echo date('H:i:s');
echo "<br>";
echo 'Hello';
echo "<br>";
sleep(1);
flush();

echo 'Goodbye';
echo "<br>";
sleep(1);
flush();

echo 'The End';
?>
```

Comment: I guess JavaScript would be better at that.

Comment: try usleep maybie, `usleep(1000000);`

Comment: This can work but it depends a little on the browser and the server - javascript/ajax maybe a better thing if its something you're retrieving from server side.

Answer (score 3):

As PHP is executed server-side, the user won't get the output until the script is finished executing. To add a visible delay of outputting messages, you would have to use JavaScript or another Client-Side executed scripting language.

Comment: To expand on this...if you need to access server side data after the page is loaded, then use Ajax to make a call back to the server so you get the most recent data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery in somewhat this way: (Assuming that your text is initialised with hello)

```
 $('#id-of-your-tag-containing-text').fadeOut(500, function() {
       $('#id-of-your-tag-containing-text').html("GoodBye!");
       $('#id-of-your-tag-containing-text').fadeIn(500);
       $('#id-of-your-tag-containing-text').fadeOut(500, function() {
              $('#id-of-your-tag-containing-text').html("The End!");
        });
       $('#id-of-your-tag-containing-text').fadeIn(500);
}); //Note that the number 500 represents the time delay in milliseconds.
```